# JPQL COALESCE is not working in RepositoryTest

Tags: jpql

I'm trying to write tests for my repository methods. The part in the screenshot is marked as a syntax error from Intellij. But when I execute it in the JPA console its working and also calling it with my Rest Endpoint it works and gives me a result. But when I do it with a unit test it's not working and throws this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
> at  ...
> ... 32 more
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ) required: , in statement [select ... where .. and (coalesce(?) is null or psq0_.id not in  (?)) and (psq_.companyId in (?))]

[image]

Is there a way to fix this syntax error shown by IntelliJ for COALESCE(:questionIds)? I guess this would also fix my tests.

SomeEntity.class

```
@NamedQuery(name = SomeEntity.QUERY_COUNT_QUESTIONS, query = "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT psq.id) FROM SomeEntity AS psq WHERE ...AND (COALESCE(:questionIds) IS NULL OR psq.id NOT IN (:questionIds)) AND ... ")
```

SomeRepository.class:

```
    public Long countQuestions(..., final List<Long> questionIds) {
        final Query countQuery = em.createNamedQuery(SomeEntity.QUERY_COUNT_QUESTIONS);

        final QueryParameter queryParameter = QueryParameter.with(...).and(QUESTION_IDS, !questionIds.isEmpty() ? questionIds : null);

        JPAUtils.setQueryParameters(countQuery, queryParameter);
        return  (Long) countQuery.getSingleResult();
    }
```

SomeRepositoryTest.class

````
    public void testCountQuestions_shouldFilterQuestion() {
        final Long questionsCount = repo.countQuestions(...,List.of(questionId));
        assertEquals((Long)2L, questionsCount);
    }
    ```
````

```
SOLUTION:
SomeEntity.class => remove COALESCE
@NamedQuery(name = SomeEntity.QUERY_COUNT_QUESTIONS, query = "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT psq.id) FROM SomeEntity AS psq WHERE ...AND (psq.id NOT IN (:questionIds)) AND ... ")

SomeRepository.class => push -1L as falback
final QueryParameter queryParameter = QueryParameter.with(...).and(QUESTION_IDS, !questionIds.isEmpty() ? questionIds : questionIds.add(-1L));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `coalesce` is used to handle `null`s.

Do try `coalesce(x,y)`
Of course `x` being your `questionIds` and `y` is supposed to be your desired parameter if `questionIds` is null.

Or if you just want to check if your `questionIds` is null, you don't need to use `coalesce` at all. You can use sth like
`AND (:questionIds is null or psq.id not in (:questionIds))`

*EDIT*

I think I understand your question now,
Maybe you can try something like:

```
@NamedQuery(name = SomeEntity.QUERY_COUNT_QUESTIONS, 
query = "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT psq.id) FROM SomeEntity AS psq 
WHERE ...AND (COALESCE(:questionIds, 0) IS NULL 
OR psq.id NOT IN (:questionIds)) AND ... ")
```

Note that I have added `COALESCE(:questionIds, 0) IS NULL`, if your `questionIds` is null then the `0` will be taken as result and this will be checked against `IS NULL` which ovbiously is false.

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: yes, I want to check if questionIds is null to not proceed with the second part 
=> psq.id not in (:questionIds) will throw error in case its empty.

:questionIds is null => this will throw error when there is more than one enty in questionIds; 

I think it was this error Operand should contain 1 column(s) thats why I'm using coalesce

Comment: Can you show the part of code where it is being  used?
Why don't you just use a simple `IF` condtion?
`if(quertionIds !=null)`{
  your condition
}
`

Comment: I do:
final QueryParameter queryParameter = QueryParameter.with(COMPANY_IDS, companyIds).and(QUESTION_IDS, !questionIds.isEmpty() ? questionIds : null);

Comment: Can you edit your question post your piece of code?

Comment: done. And I know I can just move the named query out of the Entity class and build it with createQuery in the repository, but I just wanted to know if I can improve the coalesce part, without moving the whole query out of the entity class...

Comment: See the edited part.

Comment: when I do it with `COALESCE(:questionIds, 0) IS NULL` => I get 0 results back. So I end up with my other solution, removing the named query from the enitity class and build it with a if condition... CriteriaBuilder could also be a solution...

Comment: ok, I found even an easier solution. I just fill the list with -1 in the case its empty, since the ids start with 0... so I can still use NamedQuery and no need for COALESCE

Comment: can you show how you do it? Let's learn